# rsync isn't creating files or folders

Tags: 12.04, networking, samba, rsync

I'm still relatively new to Ubuntu and Linux.  I've got a windows machine with a DAS.  I've got about 5TB of data on it, and I want to use my server running 12.04 to back it up daily / weekly.  I've got a Drobo attached to my server.  I'm mounting the network drive using:

`sudo mount -o username=username,password=******** //192.168.1.100/Storage /mnt/Storage`

Everything mounts correctly and I can read and write files.  The Drobo mounts automatically at startup, and I can read and write files to it just fine.  I've used the cp command to copy files from the network drive to the Drobo and everything works correctly.  Then I try rsync, and while rsync looks like it's running correctly, nothing gets copied over.  Here's the command I'm using.

`sudo rsync -av --delete /mnt/Storage /media/Drobo`

So after about 2-3 days of running (like it's actually copying), it says complete and yet no files were copied.  I've ran it on smaller folders with just a few files and nothing copies over.  No folders, no files.  Is there something I'm doing wrong here?

EDIT: As requested, the Drobo is a 5D attached via USB 3.0 formatted as NTFS.  Here are the results of df -h.

`Filesystem               Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda6                184G  6.8G  168G   4% /
udev                     7.7G  4.0K  7.7G   1% /dev
tmpfs                    3.1G  1.1M  3.1G   1% /run
none                     5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
none                     7.8G  160K  7.8G   1% /run/shm
/dev/sdb2                 16T  5.4T   11T  34% /media/Drobo
//192.168.1.101/Storage  7.3T  5.2T  2.2T  71% /mnt/Storage`

Brent

Comment: Drobo make many devices, which one do you have? I assume this is a NAS, not a simple drive right? Is the NAS running Linux? Does it have `rsync`? If it took 2 days it must have been doing something. Check the disk usage on your local drive and the Drobo, do you see an increase somewhere corresponding to the expected size?

Comment: Sorry, no it's a Drobo 5D, so it's directly attached via USB 3.0. It's formatted NTFS, as Drobo's don't allow for ext4.  The disk already had an old backup of the main data on it, so I'm guessing it was comparing the data correctly, however there are no new files or updates.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and include those details. Also include the output of `mount` and `df -h` when the Drobo is connected.

Comment: You have the verbose option on. Perhaps you could try using rsync to copy a subset of your desired result and let us see what rsync says is did?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you guys for the help, this appears to be a dumb user error.  I didn't realize when copying files like so:

```
sudo rsync -av --delete /mnt/Storage /media/Drobo
```

It would be making a folder inside Drobo called Storage.  Apparently I needed `/` after Storage and Drobo.  Interesting that the `cp` command doesn't, yet `rsync` does.  Anyways, I noticed when testing another folder double nested names and realized my error.

Thanks community!